# Slim with Eloquent URL rendering and updating issue

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, slim

I'm using Slim Framework with Eloquent ORM.

I have the following table:

```
album
-----------------
album_id
user_id
album_name
album_description
```

I could create a new record in album table. Successfully. And now I'm trying to edit album records.

In `view_album.php`, I'm listing all the albums with the respective links to edit their name and description. Once clicked, that link redirects to `localhost/authentication/album`.

Here is the code, I did for editing:

```
<?php    
$app->get('/edit_album/:album_id', function($album_id) use ($app) {

    $app->render('album/edit_album.php', [
        'albums' => $app->album->where('album_id', $album_id)->first(),
    ]);
})->name('edit.album');

$app->post('/edit_album/:album_id', function($album_id) use ($app) {

    $request = $app->request;

    $album_description = $request->post('album_description');
    $album_name = $request->post('album_name');

    $v = $app->validation;

    $v->validate([
        'album_name' => [$album_name, 'required|uniquealbum_name|max(50)'],
        'album_description' => [$album_description, 'required|max(500)']
    ]);

    if ($v->passes()) {

        $album = $app->album->where('album_id', $album_id)->update([
            'album_name' => $album_name,
            'album_description' => $album_description,
        ]);

        return $app->response->redirect($app->urlFor('view.albums'));
    }

    $app->render('album/edit_album.php', [     
        'errors' => $v->errors(),
        'request' => $request,
    ]);
})->name('post.albumEdit');
```

Actual problems are:

1. If the form validation fails, it outputs errors, but the user is redirected to
   `http://localhost/authentication/public/edit_album/:album_id`, instead of `http://localhost/authentication/public/edit_album/6`. Where 6 is the `album_id` from `album` table.
2. The update query is not updating the table record at all. As my query is to update the record where `album_id` is 6.

Comment: That's weird because in your code it's clear you're rendering the view when the validation doesn't pass. BTW, what is the validation library in use here?

Comment: Is `album_id` your primary key?

Comment: yes, it is primary key

Comment: How do you handle the `insert` operation?